# How to write .5 in printf in C?

Tags: c, formatting, printf

I want to print 0.5 value in ".5" form in ANSI C? 
I searched the web and stackoverflow, but I did not find what I want.
I tried both "%.1f" and "%0.1f ". But neiter of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such specification in `C` to print fractional numbers without `0` at the begin. BTW you can use this code for your case:

```
printf(".%d", (int)(0.5*10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this workaround:

```
double f = 0.5;

printf(".%u\n" , (unsigned)((f + 0.05) * 10));
```

Comment: Every time someone is ahead of me :)

Answer (score 1):

After accept answer

Should code need to avoid troubles with *large* floating point values, INF, NaN or edge conditions like

```
printf(".%d", (int)(0.46*10)); // prints "0.4"
```

Post-process the string.

```
void PrintdNoLead0(double x) {
  const char *format = "%.1f\n";
  if (fabs(x) < 1.0) {
    char buf[10];  // Some buffer large enough for x in range -1<x<1
    sprintf(buf, format, x);
    char *p = strchr(&buf[1], '.');
    if (p[-1] == '0') {
      memmove(&p[-1], p, strlen(p));
    }
    fputs(buf, stdout);
  } else {
    printf(format, x);
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you so I told in my solution that it is only acceptable in his case (with 0.5).

Comment: @Seprum you could have also written `printf(".5");` if your solution is only acceptable for 0.5